# Use link in app code can cause rejection from google play?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

If I use any link in my app code.
That can cause of rejection from google play?
Google play review team install the app and review that manually?

Comment: `If I use any link in my app code` - Please elaborate more on this. Are you opening external links in WebView or in ChromeCustomTabs or something else?

Comment: I want use web link to fetch the data

Comment: I assume you use it like an api service, if the api is yours then its fine. If not & you do not have the permission to use it then the owner can always file a complaint. If the api service / backend is yours then you are free to use it as you want, there shouldn't be any policy issues.